# Unity Attribute Error when resetting

Tags: unity, reset

Lately, as I was trying to install themes and stuff for my desktop with Compiz, I enabled the Desktop Cube. I resolved the conflicts, then all the menu-bars disappeared.  After a Google research, i found some sites that told to reset Unity using the terminal command:

```
unity --reset
```

But there, I got an "AttributeError: object has no 'str' attribute" (I don't remember the exact error, but it was an AttributeError about string), line 83 at `if current_profile_gconfvalue.get_string() == 'unity':`.

It is easy to correct it, with a "try: ... except:" block, but where do I report it, and where could I help?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to report a bug on [launchpad](http://www.launchpad.net/ubuntu), for the Unity package. Before creating a new bug, make sure that a similar bug hasn't been reported yet. A more detailed description of how to correctly report a bug can be found on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: I doubt such a bug would be useful. There's a reason the cube and all the other stuff in there is turned off -- a bunch of that stuff is untested.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is "useful" or not. It's a bug, and therefore it needs to be reported and fixed.

Comment: `unity --reset` is supposed to undo all custom settings. If it fails to do so, that sounds like a bug to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unity tracks [bugs on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity).

The general idea is:

1. search if it was found before; if so add yourself to the affected people;
2. otherwise create a bug report and file it.